# errorFormatter koa-async-validator

Tags: error-handling, koa

I am trying to apply `errorFormatter` in ``koa-async-validator` (https://www.npmjs.com/package/koa-async-validator):

I do (as in their example):

```
app.use(koaValidator({
  errorFormatter: function(param, msg, value) {
      var namespace = param.split('.')
      , root    = namespace.shift()
      , formParam = root;

    while(namespace.length) {
      formParam += '[' + namespace.shift() + ']';
    }
    return {
      param : formParam,
      msg   : msg,
      value : value
    };
  }
}));
```

But how should I call that `errorFormatter`?

The below does not seem to format errors:

```
let errors = await ctx.validationErrors().errorFormatter()
```

Or

```
errors.errorFormatter()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to call directly it.

you have to call

```js
let errors = await ctx.validationErrors()
```

or

```js
let errors = await ctx.validationErrors(true)
```

where errors will have the format you defined in `errorFormatter` for each error.